# PyQt cross-platform way of communicating between running applications

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Hey guys/ladies of python mastery, need some help.
I'm using PyQt to create some integrated ui elements for an application written in python (appA) that runs on windows/linux/osx, I need those elements to be able to communicate with a PyQt app (appB) I have written that runs separately (same host).

What would be the best (cross-platform) approach to creating a communication link between the integrated ui elements in one app and the standalone app i have written?
I want to be able to send/receive messages from appA to appB...

For example appA launches, integrated ui elements load in a form of an input field with a 'Send' button. Upon entering data and hitting 'Send' a test is performed to check if appB is running/needs to be launched, after appB launches, data arrives at appB and appB sends a confirmation of delivery back to appA and vice versa. This needs to work with least delay and hackery on windows/linux/osx.

I was looking at DBus but that looks a little buggy for WIN, win32api is good for WIN but useless elsewhere, maybe there is a magic bullet to these things. 
Any links to tutorials/sites/docs would be great or if u have some ready code  :) ! whatever  , thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use raw sockets, you should try `zmq` (zeromq). You can find a good introduction to `zmq` [here](http://nichol.as/zeromq-an-introduction)

Comment: Thanks Viktor, This is very helpful. I'm going to shortlist zmq as a method. I really like the promised speed and ability to scale, maybe I can couple this with [Google Protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

Comment: You can send over zmq connection whatever you want.